# Would it be possible to run an application while not meeting it's minimum memory (RAM) requirement?

Tags: memory

There are many situations where your computer may not meet the minimum hardware requirements of an application (architecture, processing power, memory, storage, display adapter, peripherals).

If I have a computer with 256MB of memory and am trying to run an application with a minimum memory requirement of 512MB. Is it possible to run?

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible to use hard drive space as "swap", ie virtual RAM, which pushes the least used RAM to disks.  Most modern OS's do this seemlessly, however the penalty for excessively using disk as RAM is a MASSIVE performance decrease to the point where its probably not useable.  It also places excessive wear on the hard drive (but again, its probably so slow as to be not useable).

Also, 256 Megs of RAM is laughably small for a PC, with entry level PC's having 20 times that amount.  If your time is worth anything, get a computer which meets the minimum specs.

Contrary to the assertion, there are very, very few situations where a computer does not meet the minimum specs for software.